# Python3.7 in terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Sorry for dumb question, but recently I've reinstalled OS on my computer, and I'm having a bit of an issue with Linux terminal.
Previously i was able to run python3.7 from terminal using "python" command, but now, instead of 3.7 - it runs 2.7, which was installed by default. Is there any way to replace 2.7 with 3.7 in "python" command, without having to type "python3.7" or "python3" (I've also installed 3.6 by accident, so it's used when executing "python3")?
I'm also having the same issue with pip. When i run pip - it says that command not found, but when i type "pip3" - it runs pip3 for 3.6, and I'm only able to run 3.7's pip through "python3.7 -m pip".

Comment: The usual way to do this is make `/usr/bin/python` (or whatever the exact location is) be a symlink to the python3.7 binary.

Comment: @JohnGordon but how can i do this? I know how to make symlinks, but where do i find 3.7's binary?

Comment: @Gargoyle If you create a symlink to change which version of python is invoked you may run into problems down the road. More information on [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/226615/335444).

Comment: `which python3.7` will show the actual location of the binary.  But as @Jason said, you might want to investigate further before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You system's default version of Python is Python2.x, if you want to use Python3.x you can you one of the following methods:

1. Create a virtual environment with python3.x. This is recommended so that when you install modules etc. it doesn't interfere with your system's python. [Link to venv docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

`python3 -m venv /path/to/virtualenvironment`

And use by

`source /path/to/virtualenvironment/bin/activate`

Instead of typing the above line you can place a function in your `.bashrc`:

```
# My functions
workon() {
        source ~/.venvs/$1/bin/activate
}
```

Now provide your virtual environments are saved in `~/.venvs/`, typing `workon new_env` will run virtual envrionment called `new_env`. To stop using the venv, type `deactivate`.

2. Create an alias for Python to Python3:

In your `.bash_aliases` add the line:

`alias python='python3'`
(If in future you DO want `python2`, type `python2` or `\python` (the leading backslash tells `bash` not to use your alias.